# Powershell script to Get-Content of last line in multple files (loop array)

Tags: arrays, windows, loops, powershell

I have a folder with a list of files (*.log files) which all end with the following line, showing the output (different files will have different amounts) e.g.:

```
Total MB moved to Archive = 369.06444644928
```

I have the following query which will get the result of the first file in the folder:

```
Get-ChildItem $path| Where-Object {$_.Name} | Get-Content | select -last 1
```

I also have the following query which will output a list of all the log files:

```
Get-ChildItem $Path |  ForEach {
Write-Host $_.Name}
```

I just want to create a loop to print a list of each last line of each log, not the log name or the last line of one log. And then the complex part, to pull the number part and add these together. Any tips?

Comment: "print a list of each last line of each log, not the log name or the last line of one log" - I'm not sure I understand this. You want a string like "file1.txt - 369.06444644928"?

Comment: Hello, sorry for the confusion, I was thinking of longer way to script this. Effectively just need the script to write output of the total number of MB moved (so just sum of last string in each .log file in folder). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading the question correctly, this should work:

```
Get-ChildItem $Path |
  ForEach {
            Write-Host $_.Name
            [double]$MB_Moved += (Get-Content $_.FullName -Tail 1) -replace '.+?([\d.]+)\s*','$1' 
          }
```